# Install ckeditor in YII framework

Tags: yii, ckeditor

I am using Yii Framework version 1.1.14. I am able to install FCK editor but I want to use ck editor.

I download files from this links http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/the-ckeditor-integration/
and upload files on location but i get this error
[check image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9693.png)

I am using this code in my view

```
<?php $this->widget('application.extensions.ckeditor.CKEditorWidget',array(
    'model'=>$model,                # Data-Model (form model)
    'attribute'=>'content',         # Attribute in the Data-Model
    'height'=>'400px',
    'width'=>'100%',
    'toolbarSet'=>'Basic',          # EXISTING(!) Toolbar (see: ckeditor.js)
    'ckeditor'=>Yii::app()->basePath.'/../ckeditor/ckeditor.php',
                                    # Path to ckeditor.php
    'ckBasePath'=>Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/ckeditor/',
                                    # Relative Path to the Editor (from Web-Root)
    'css' => Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/css/index.css',
                                    # Additional Parameters
) ); ?>
```

Comment: i can give you a manual codding instruction if you want

Comment: Can you please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download CKEditor from http://ckeditor.com/download  (Select full package) and put it in your root directory  (You can put it any where according to you)

Add this is your view file

```
<script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/ckeditor/ckeditor.js'; ?>"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'Articles_meta_description');
</script>
```

Where `Articles_meta_description` is id of input fields

If you want add image upload in ckeditor you can download KCfinder from this link http://kcfinder.sunhater.com/download and put it in your root directory (you can put it any where according to you)

**Set upload path into session** : in your view file

```
$_SESSION['KCFINDER']['disabled'] = false; // enables the file browser in the admin
$_SESSION['KCFINDER']['uploadURL'] = Yii::app()->baseUrl."/uploads/"; // URL for the uploads folder
$_SESSION['KCFINDER']['uploadDir'] = Yii::app()->basePath."/../uploads/"; //
```

> For ckeditor with image upload

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'Articles_meta_description', {  // input field id
         filebrowserBrowseUrl: '<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>/kcfinder/browse.php?type=files',
         filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: '<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>/kcfinder/browse.php?type=images',
         filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl: '<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>/kcfinder/browse.php?type=flash',
         filebrowserUploadUrl: '<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>/kcfinder/upload.php?type=files',
         filebrowserImageUploadUrl: '<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>/kcfinder/upload.php?type=images',
         filebrowserFlashUploadUrl: '<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>/kcfinder/upload.php?type=flash'
    });
</script>
```

Comment: what is the problem ?

Comment: It is displaying simple text area and this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getEditor' of undefined" occured in console

Comment: @Dipali remove your widget and follow my answer, open your browser console and is there any error display.